# Android, listview expand to show text

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView made up of news headlines, I want it so that when I click on a headline the item will expand and show text relating to the headline. I've had a look at using the ExpandableListView but that is for adding a list to a list item. Whereas I want to add a string to a list item. Can anyone point me in the right direction about how to go about doing this?

Comment: Use Expandable List View for that...check this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html and this sample tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: I have had a look at that, but everything I find on it, is about adding a list to the list item. I don't have that, I have two lists, one with the headlines and one with the descriptions, I want each item to correspond on the expansion

Comment: Yes right first list will be for the headline and second list for the desc.If you see the expandable view the parent data will be the first list and the child data will be the second list.

Comment: Assuming you have a item layout to render each headline in your list, you can add another TextView to the item layout with Visibility Gone. Use this textview to hold the detail text relating to the headline. Then when you click on any item in the list, just toggle the visibility of the new TextView